# how to show/hide a component in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a component tha its supposed to appear when you click a button. I've tried to create a `Visibility` component and switching on/off the visibility property. It works when I turn it off but when I turn it on it doens't render the component back.

Answer (score 4):

Did you forget to use `setState`???

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {
  bool visibility = true;

  toggleVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      visibility = !visibility;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Visibility(
        visible: visibility,
        child: Text('visible'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: toggleVisibility),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, but the button is actually outside from the component i want to show/hide

Comment: @k1k4ss0 in that case you should pass this `toggleVisibility` method as a `callback` to that component. You can read about passing callbacks on this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-working-with-callback-functions/

Comment: you should have a look to provider package and view/model and avoid using multiples callback to update the state of the widgets : https://pub.dev/packages/provider